# Count distinct values of field within jsonb in sequelize

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

I have a table similar to:

```
+==========|===========+
|id        |primary key|
|----------|-----------|
|jdoc      |jsonb      |
+==========|===========+
```

`jdoc` will possibly have a field called `abc` within it. I need to find the distinct count of values in `jdoc->'abc'`. How do I accomplish this using sequelize?

I tried using the following:

```
Entity.count({
  distinct: true,
  col: 'jdoc.abc'
})
```

This does not work and give the error that field `jdoc.abc` does not exist in table `Entity`.

What is the right way to get this working?
Should I resort to using raw queries if there is no native support to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found an answer. It uses `sequelize.literal` as the input to `Entity.count`.

```
Entity.count({
  distinct: true,
  col: sequelize.literal('jsonb_extract_path(jdoc, \'abc\')')
})
```